# Backbone view only rendering for a split second

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a main Backbone view for my app and I'm having trouble rendering a template based on a button click.

If the user clicks the submit button, it should display template2, otherwise it should display template1. Right now, when I click the submit button, template2 only displays for a second and then disappears before template1 appears again.

Here's a simplified version of the code without the other app functionalities

```
app.viewExample = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#in",
  template1: _.template( $('#one').html() ),
  template2: _.template( $('#two').html() ),

  events: {
    'click .submit': 'result',
  },

  initialize: function() {
    var bool = false;
    this.listenTo(app.col, 'all', this.render);
  },

  render: function() {
    if (this.bool) {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * app.opts.length);
      var value = app.col.at(rand).get("title");
      this.$el.html(this.template2( {
        result: value
      }));
    }      
    else if (!this.bool) {
      var total = app.col.length;
      this.$el.html(this.template1( {
        total: total
      }));
    }   
  },

  result: function() {
    this.bool = true; 
    this.render(); 
  }
});
```

*app.col is the collection for this app

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template1">
    <span id="count"> Currently <%= total %> <%= total === 1 ? 'option' : 'options' %>
    </span>
    <button id="clear-all">Clear all</button>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="template2">
    <div class="result">
    Result: <%= result %>
    </div>
    <button class="restart">Restart</button>
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<section id="in">
    //stuff
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you show your template code as well as what app.col is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of little problems here.

1. Your view is looking for the wrong templates, you have:

   ```
   template1: _.template( $('#one').html() ),
   template2: _.template( $('#two').html() ),
   ```

   but `<script id="template1">` and `<script id="template2">`. Those need to agree with each other.
2. `var bool = false` in your `initialize` does **not** set `this.bool`, that just declares and initializes a local variable inside `initialize`. You'd want `this.bool = false` to initialize an object property.
3. Your view's `events` are looking for clicks on `class="submit"`:

   ```
   events: {
     'click .submit': 'result',
   }
   ```

   but your HTML starts out with a `class="submit"` element and the templates have `id="clear-all"` and `class="restart"` so the buttons in the templates won't do anything. If you only have one `<button>` per template then you can say:

   ```
   events: {
     'click button': 'result',
   }
   ```
4. Some browsers get the default `type` wrong for `<button>` so you should always specify it explicitly: `<button type="button">` instead of `<button>`.

Once you fix up those issues, it seems to work okay: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ThQ8V/3/

Comment: Ah thanks alot! Sorry about the view templating name mismatch, tried to simplify my code to post here and got mixed up.

Comment: I figured at least some of the problems were related to the stripped down demo but I tried to cover them all just in case.